# Why can't I get Automapper Parameterization to work

Tags: c#, automapper

Given the following Automapper profile :

```
 public class MyProfile: Profile
 {
   private int? _injectedInt;

    public MyProfile()
    {

      CreateMap<objectA, objectB>()
     .ForMember(e => e.myNullableInt, x => x.MapFrom(s =>_injectedInt.HasValue ? 100 : 0));


    }
  }
```

And the following code :

```
var result = queryableOfObjectA.ProjectTo<objectB>(new { _injectedInt = 1 });

var resultingValue = result.FirstOrDefault().myNullableInt;
```

**Why is "resultingValue" returning 0 instead of 100?**

I can't see what I have done wrong from the docs:

http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html#parameterization

Comment: Try making it a local.

Comment: My apologies but I have no idea what you mean by that... can you provide me with a link or a code example as to what you mean?

Comment: what happens if you remove the private access modifier from the _injectedInt ?

Comment: No difference I’m afraid :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the place where `_injectedInt` is declared might be the issue.  I have written following test and 100 is returned.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest19
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(expression => expression.AddProfile(new MyProfile()));

        var queryableOfObjectA = new List<objectA>
        {
            new objectA
            {
                myNullableInt = 10
            }
        };

        var result = queryableOfObjectA.AsQueryable().ProjectTo<objectB>(new { _injectedInt = (int?)1 });

        var resultingValue = result.FirstOrDefault()?.myNullableInt;

        Assert.AreEqual(100, resultingValue);
    }
}

public class MyProfile : Profile
{
    public MyProfile()
    {
        int? _injectedInt = null;

        CreateMap<objectA, objectB>()
            .ForMember(e => e.myNullableInt, x => x.MapFrom(s => _injectedInt.HasValue ? 100 : 0));
    }
}

public class objectA
{
    public int myNullableInt { get; set; }
}

public class objectB
{
    public int myNullableInt { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ODawg that's done the trick. Could have sworn I tried that already but I guess not. Many Thanks

Comment: No problem @Jon Ryan. Glad I was able to help. Cheers,